# Out of Memory error in imageLoader

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am using bitmap and lazy loading but some time its show out of memory error in this line plz help me.

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Thanks frds

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: Java using in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how many of these do u do? cus' you might just got to the memory capacity.

assuming you didn't i'll show you to these question:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935793/bitmap-out-of-memory-issues)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697760/android-out-of-memory-exception-when-creating-bitmap)

what happends is because you are loading the bitmap directly, which consumes a lot of memory. Instead use a scaled down version of the picture in _profileBitmap. This guy explains it pretty well. http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/05/solving-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's Android (what i suppose) you have to be carfully with "lazy" loading. You don't have 4Gb RAM. You only have some MB. You can scale your pic down do save space and you can "reuse" one image if you need it more than one time.

Comment: didn't i said this ? i said he has to scale ... and your link say this too ... the problem is the realy limited heap size and not bitmap (which is not small too)